# How to call a function on "Done" button of jquery time picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery time picker in my page. I want to call a function on this timepicker when the DONE button is clicked. so How to do this?

Please help me.

Comment: `$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});`

Answer (score 4):

Yu should do that onClose

```
$('#example16_end').datetimepicker({
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
     alert('closing');
},
```

Comment: although this works, careful - it executes also when timepicker is closed by losing focus on the textbox, so not just on clicking Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a click event with 'Done' button in beforeShow callback of datepicker like this...

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  showButtonPanel: true, 
  beforeShow: function (input) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var btn = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-datepicker-close");
        btn.bind("click", function () {
            $(input).datepicker( "setDate", new Date() );
            $(input).datepicker( "hide" );
        });
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

This will work.